# How to ensure this is the generic type referenced in my class signature?

Tags: java, generics

Suppose we have three classes - `AbstractMessage`, `AbstractEngine`, and `AbstractAction`. These three classes all reference each other in a generic fashion so each Engine has a corresponding message and action and you can refer to them directly in the code.

```
public class MyMessage<M extends AbstractMessage<M,E,A>, E extends AbstractEngine<M,E,A>, A extends AbstractAction<M,E,A>> {
```

This is working fine, but when I attempt to enforce behavior at the highest level I run into some problems. My AbstractAction class has an `applyTo` method defined thusly:

```
protected abstract M applyTo(E engine, Object guarantee);
```

and my AbstractEngine class has this

```
private final M apply(A action) {
    return action.apply(this, this.guarantee);
}
```

And it is on this line that it balks - complaining that:

```
The method applyTo(E, Object) in the type AbstractAction<M,E,A> is not
applicable for the arguments (AbstractEngine<M,E,A>, Object)
```

Now the reason for this is clear - the E in question might be some OTHER AbstractEngine and there's no way to know if the subclass we're calling this from is actually an `E`.

My question is, how can I say for certainty that if you're going to `class MyEngine extends AbstractEngine<M...,E...,A...>` that `MyEngine` is **MUST** be an `E`? And to have this certainty baked into `AbstractEngine`?

Here is a small example that illustrates the problem.

```
class EngineExample {

    static abstract class AbEng<A extends AbAct<A,M,E>, M extends AbMes<A,M,E>, E extends AbEng<A,M,E>> {

        final M func(A act) {
            return act.apply(this); // compile error here
        }

    }

    static abstract class AbMes<A extends AbAct<A,M,E>, M extends AbMes<A,M,E>, E extends AbEng<A,M,E>> {

    }

    static abstract class AbAct<A extends AbAct<A,M,E>, M extends AbMes<A,M,E>, E extends AbEng<A,M,E>> {

        abstract void apply(E e);

    }

    static class RealEng extends AbEng<RealAct, RealMes, RealEng> {

    }

    static class RealMes extends AbMes<RealAct, RealMes, RealEng> {

    }

    static class RealAct extends AbAct<RealAct, RealMes, RealEng> {

        void apply(RealEng eng) {
            System.out.println("applied!");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @Tezra Not everything needs a mcve. I do not have a type error. I'm sorry that you don't understand the question, but perhaps you should read it again. Perhaps also read Valentin's answer which is an attempt to what the problem is.

Comment: Tezra, A will always be an `AbstractAction` - that's right there in the first code snippet. And as far as restricting their types at compile time, I don't want to have to define them on every class willy-nilly - I want to declare them at instance time. I've used this paradigm before, and it works very well *EXCEPT* this one stupid problem of types not knowing they are the type specified in the generic descriptor. That's it.

Comment: @Tezra Sorry no, on each of `AbstractMessage`, `AbstractAction` and `AbstractEngine` you have the `M extends AbstractMessage<M,E,A>, E extends AbstractEngine<M,E,A>, A extends AbstractAction<M,E,A>` rider. I figured that was kind of implied by the question, but it appears not.

Comment: Your original point was that I had a type error (as you said, Action != Engine) but you had misread the text. Nice little switcheroo there. And I know exactly what the safety problem is - I'm looking for someone who might know how to solve that safety problem. Your comments have gone from getting my post wrong... to saying what my post is saying... So now that you actually understand the situation, well, you have no solution - and neither do I - I'm looking for someone who does.

Comment: @Tezra As for "why a MVCe (sic) is always helpful" sorry, but no. It's not always helpful. The person who can actually answer the question is fully aware of the environment I'm dealing with and what the implications are. If you really want an mcve I can make you one... Just for you...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151426/discussion-between-tezra-and-corsika).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Use loosest valid parameter type

The simplest solution, is to not actually enforce that `this isInstanceOf E`. The rules of abstraction already guarantee that this is a safe operation, so it will just work if you change the parameter to just allow any Engine.

```
abstract Action<E> {
  public void apply(Engine<?> e, Object o) {
    e.doSomething(o);
  }
}
```

or

```
abstract Action<E> {
  <T extends Engine<?>> public T apply(T e, Object o) {
    return e.doSomething(o);
  }
}
```

## Use a type-safe wrapper

Another solution is to create another class that binds these 3 together, and move the interaction calls to the wrapper.

```
abstract System<A extends Action, M extends Message, E extends Engine> {
    abstract void apply(A action, E engine) {
        engine.render(action.apply())
    }
}
```

Or have the wrapper class take an instance of these 3 and use the passed in versions. This basically is the "allow anything close enough" solution, and adding another class to manage how they can and can't talk to each other.

## Pre-cast check

You can also make a reference cast on construction to throw an error if the cast setup is invalid.

```
private final E dis = (E) this;
```

This really just moves the problem from from always on compile time, to sometimes on run time, so in general, not a safe/stable solution.

---

This next solution is a bit specific to your case (using info from our discussion). Basically, you want to define a method in an abstract class that class A and B can inherit, but A and B should not be interchangeable using their base class.

## Just use polymophism and use generics just as a type segregator

Here is a modification of the MVCe that uses polymorphism instead, using generics only as a kind of type-category-exclusive-locking mechanism. Basically, Type is a semantic interface to say whether semantically, it makes sense for these classes to talk to each other. (A Physics Engine and Light Engine may share some functionality, but it would make no sense to let them be interchangeable.)

```
class test {

    public static void main(String[] rawrs) {
        RealEng re = new RealEng();
        RealAct ra = new RealAct();
        MockAct ma = new MockAct();
        ra.apply(re);
        // Remove all code related to Type interface if next line should compile
        ma.apply(re); // compile error here
    }

    static interface Type {
    }

    static interface Real extends Type {
    };

    static interface Mock extends Type {
    };

    static abstract class AbEng<T extends Type> {

        final void func(AbAct<T> act) {
            act.apply(this); // compile error here
        }

    }

    static abstract class AbMes<T extends Type> {

    }

    static abstract class AbAct<T extends Type> {

        abstract void apply(AbEng<T> e);

    }

    static class RealEng extends AbEng<Real> {

    }

    static class RealMes extends AbMes<Real> {

    }

    static class RealAct extends AbAct<Real> {
        @Override
        void apply(AbEng<Real> eng) {
            System.out.println("applied!");
        }
    }

    static class MockAct extends AbAct<Mock> {
        @Override
        void apply(AbEng<Mock> eng) {
            System.out.println("applied!");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: For the record, it is this Option 6 that most elegantly solves the problem.

Comment: Option 6 in corsiaKa's comment is "Just use polymophism and use generics just as a type segregator". I edited the question to try and make it much clearer to other readers.

Answer (score 2):

Recursive type-parameters in Java generics are often troublesome.

The problem here is that paradoxically there in no way that you can guaranteed that `this` makes reference to an instance of `E`; the only thing that we known about `this` is that it also extends `Engine<M, A, E>` but not that is actually `E`.

Obvious solution is to add a cast (`(E)this`) and that might be an acceptable solution but you must make clear in the contract (thru javadoc or other documentations) that `Engine` extending classes must assign `E` to themselves.

Another solution simply change those method signatures to be a bit more flexible and instead `E` accept any engine that extends `Engine<M, A, E>`.

```
protected abstract M applyTo(AbstractEngine<M, A, E> engine, Object guarantee);
```

Also consider to reduce the number of type-parameters whenever possible. For example does Engine need to make reference to its own type? Does it have any method that accepts or returns and engine that must be of the same type/class?

**EDIT**

If you want to keep the `E` type parameter in `applyTo` another option is to create a field typed `E` in AbstractEngine that would be the one passed to the apply to. This field in fact would make reference to `this` but once it has been "casted" safely at construction.:

```
public class AbstractEngine<M extends ..., A extends ..., E extends ...> {
    private final E engine;

    protected AbstractEngine(final E engine) {
       this.engine = Objects.requiresNonNull(engine);
    }
}

public class MyEngine extends AbstractEngine<MyMessage, MyAction, MyEngine> {
    public MyEngine() {
       super(this);
    }
}
```

The reason this works is that when we are declaring `MyEngine` then the compiler does know that `MyEngine` is `E` and so the "cast" is safe one. Then the code in `AbstractEngine` can use the casted value safely thereafter.

The obvious inconvenience is the extra field making reference to `this`, that although is a bit of memory waste in practice is probably negligible.

Here we are adding the possibility that an engine could designate a surrogate engine to be used in their `apply` method calls. Perhaps that might be useful... but if you really want to make it impossible to use a third engine here, then you can change the code in the `AbstractEngine` constructor to compare the passed engine with `this` and fail at runtime if they are not the same.

```
protected AbstractEngine(final E engine) {
   if (engine != this) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException();
   }
   this.engine = engine;
}
```

Unfortunately this cannot be check at compilation time... the second best thing you can do is to make it part of your code tests to verify that all `AbstractEngine` extending classes are compliant so it would fail at build-time.

Comment: The Engine doesn't need it's own type for itself, but it does need to know that the Messages belong to THAT engine, not some other. I've tried other variations and always end up needing all three on all three. Like you say, generics are always trouble.

Comment: As for your solutions, I am currently casting it. But I'd prefer not to. I'd rather it work the way I want it. As for your second solution, being more flexible is the opposite of what I want. I want it rigid.

Comment: @corsika with THAT engine, do you mean engine type or instance? If the later then you would alway need to use a ref to the engine and verify in runtime.

Comment: Interesting point. When I made the comment, I intended the former. But the more I think about it, the more I realize that since these engines are not singletons (there will definitely be multiple instances of the same engine types running in a single server) that I have to think on the answer to that question. Still, I find the cast to `(E)this` to be hacky and would like to avoid it. Your question is important, though, and may complicate things.

Comment: @corsika what you can do to keep that E in applyTo and avoid the cast each time is to declare a field in AbstrsctEngine declared as .final E set by the constructor that takes is value as a parameter and the concrete engine pass themselves to that constructor. Will update answer later

Comment: @corsiKa I have added the E-keeping ```(E)``` cast free solution to my answer.